# Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from myFile.jar error

Tags: java, jar, solaris, rad

I'm using IBM's Relational Application Developer (RAD) as my IDE. I have one Java class in my project and I named it extract.java. I have couple of library files and resources files associated with my project. I exported my project as a jar file using IDE and ran it through command line on solaris environment using following query:

```
$java -jar myFile.jar
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from myFile.jar

I saw suggestions that manifest file needs to be updated. I'm not sure what does that mean since I'm new to java and any help will be great.

PS: There are no errors when I run class as Java Application from IDE on windows machine.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make a JAR an Executable JAR within RAD, do the following steps:

1. Right click on the project and select Export...
2. Select Java > Runnable JAR file and click Next.
3. In the Launch Configuration field, select your Java class that contains the `public static void main(String[] args)` method.
4. Specify the destination location.
5. Lastly, define how the libraries, if any, in your project should be packaged in the JAR.
6. Click Finish.

This should create the Manifest file with the correct Main-class header. Run the JAR with the `java -jar` command to make sure it's working.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In your jar file, you need to add or modify the file `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` corresponding to the manifest of your jar to add the attribute `Main-Class`:

```
Main-Class: my.package.MyClass
```

Assuming that `my.package.MyClass` is the Fully Qualified Name of the class that has the `main` method to call when you launch your jar file with `java -jar myFile.jar`

Comment: could you please help me understand where do i add this manifest file? does it go in RAD before i export or does it go in solaris environment? if i need to create it before export where does this file reside? if after, i assume it goes in the same directory as jar?

Comment: it is inside your jar file at `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: Please check the jar file i attached to the question. i'm not sure how will i update that? i opened that with notepad++. is there another tool i should be using to open it? Also, looked up Run Configurations for my project and MyClass is set to main class. I thought it will pick that information up while creating jar file

Comment: Actually a jar is a zip archive in which you have all your classes and resources file, so you need to add a new file in your zip

Comment: so add a file called META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in my project before exporting it as jar file?

Comment: added a file MANIFEST.MF at same location as MyClass before exporting project as a jar and received same error as before. I was unable to name my file as META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Comment: you need to create a folder `META-INF` in which you put  the file `MANIFEST.MF`